# How to set months to display in bsDaterangepicker popup?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I am using [bsDaterangepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) when clicked it shows current month and next in the popup. All date ranges in my application are in the past, so I need to show current and previous month. How can I configure that?

Answer (score 1):

You use this workaround to solve it:

In HTML:

```
 <input
      formControlName="dateRange"
      type="text"
      bsDaterangepicker
      #rangePicker="bsDaterangepicker"
      (onShown)="onDateRangePickerShow()"/>
  </div>
```

In component:

```
export class Component {

@ViewChild('rangePicker') rangePicker;

onDateRangePickerShow() {
  // This is a workaround to show previous month
  const prevMonth = new Date(moment().subtract(1, 'month'));
  this.rangePicker._datepicker.instance.monthSelectHandler({ date: prevMonth });
}
```